# Importing Accounts

Tags: android

everybody.
In my application I try to create a new Account, but I got a SecurityException during adding it: "caller uid 10028 is different than the authenticator's uid". My code is:

```
AccountManager accountManager = null;   

accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

Account sampleAccount = new Account(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_TYPE);

boolean isSuccess=false;

if (accountManager != null) {

try {

    isSuccess = accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(sampleAccount,
                        ACCOUNT_PASSWORD, null);

} catch (Exception e) {

    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this link will help:

http://loganandandy.tumblr.com/post/613041897/caller-uid-is-different

It sounds like the AccountType specified by the constant does not match up with the AccountType defined in the XML of the account-authenticator element, and if they do not match up, it throws this exception.